# Switching OpenID

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid

**I'm going insane.**

I have one account on Stack Overflow at the minute which I use happily. Then, as I follow [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/we-now-support-multiple-openids/) blog posting, I try to associate it with another GMail that I have.

*HOWEVER*.

Every time I click "Add OpenID", then log into my **NEW** GMail account that I'd like to associate it with, it logs me out of the Username/Account that I'd like to keep, and **IN** to an account that I've never used before. I'm not entirely too sure what's supposed to happen, but a wild guess would be ( In quotes to avoid confusion... if you don't want to know my opinion or why it's driving me insane, **skip**):

```
 To keep me signed into the account that I'd like to keep perhaps, 
 then add the GMail I'd like to associate it with to the account... 
 but that's not what it's doing.
```

The reason for this switch is that I now use a more professional, *super-user* type GMail, that I forward a few accounts to, therefore I'd my my SO account associated with this e-mail, instead of my *'further down the line'* GMail account.

I hope you understand my problem, what I'm asking and I do hope you can help. Thank you very much indeed.

*EDIT 1*

I've e-mailed team@stackoverflow.com before anyone suggests, to which I got no response :(

*EDIT 2*

Well, to be honest, I don't even understand the concept. Basically, with my email1@googlemail, I have the SO ID that I want to keep. Then, at email2@gmail, I seem to have another SO ID that I've never used before (It's called unknown(google) with 1 rep point.. kind of like my meta-SO ID at the minute).

Ideally, I'd like to:

DELETE whatever SO ID seems to be associated with email2@gmail

associate email1@googlemail's SO ID with with email2@gmail

Clean up the email1@googlemail by deleting whatever is associated with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I don't see any email from you, even in the junk mail folder. Are you sure your email arrived?

You have an orphan account squatting on the openid, which needs to be deleted. Email the URL to that account to us, at the email link at the bottom of every page..

Comment: Cheers, Jeff! :)

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not understand. Maybe the team has the same problem with your mail ;)

If you add a new OpenID you have to log in with this new ID. I think, that's what you are doing. But what is this account that you've never used before? Are you logged in with your new GMail account or not?

You keep both IDs, but for sure you have to log in first with the new one, so Stack Overflow knows it.